# Using JS variable in Html

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I need to access a javascript variable inside a html iFrame. Below I will mention the code which I have implemented so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sessionState = '<%=statusCookie%>'
    console.log("======JS sessionState=========="+sessionState);
    </script>
 <iframe id="rpIFrame" src="http://localhost:8080/playground/rpIFrame.jsp?session="+sessionState>
</iframe>
```

Here the console log prints the sessionState value correctly. But once I append it with the src in iFrame sessionState becomes empty. Please help me to correct this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
        var sessionState = '<%=statusCookie%>'
        document.getElementById("rpIFrame").src = "http://localhost:8080/playground/rpIFrame.jsp?session="+sessionState
    }
</script>
<iframe id="rpIFrame"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="rpIFrame" src="http://localhost:8080/playground/rpIFrame.jsp?session="+sessionState>
</iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sessionState = '<%=statusCookie%>'
    document.getElementById("rpIFrame").setAttribute(src,"http://localhost:8080/playground/rpIFrame.jsp?session="+sessionState );
</script>
```